# Problem-solving method for calculating flux on a half-cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I wanted to calculate the flux on a half-cylinder's surfaces:

$$\iint_S\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf s$$

The easiest way to go about this is to use divergence theorem, I found, so that I get

$$\iiint_V\nabla\cdot\mathbf F\,dV$$

which, for certain functions $\mathbf F$, is easier to calculate, since $dV$ is an easily calculated volume element, whereas $d\mathbf s$ has no obvious parametrization. In the case that I wanted to avoid using the divergence theorem, however, would I have to break down the half-cylinder into each of its surfaces, then add up the double integral on each?

$$\iint_{S_1}\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf s_1+\iint_{S_2}\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf s_2+\iint_{S_3}\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf s_3+\iint_{S_4}\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf s_4$$

Comment: In essence, yes.  The flux is the amount flowing out of $V$, which can be calculated as the total amount flowing out of each surface (since the stuff that's flowing out has to move through these surfaces to escape $V$).

Comment: Yes, the end-cap(s) and the curved surface have to be treated separately.